# Call a js function inside of modal window

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I'm applying some css3 effects using a function it works fine on body page but my problem is how to call that function inside a modal window? created dynamic by Ajax.

this is the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.PIE) {
        $('.secondary, .primary, .light_gray_sub').click(function() {
            PIE.attach(this);
            alert("alert XXX");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by 'modal window', 'dynamic by Ajax', and I don't see any css3 effects.

Comment: PIE is a JS library that add some css3 effects to IE

Comment: exactly, PIE.js is library, so how it works: I use my classes .secondary,.primary... to define them various effects like border-radius, box shadow... in css ,adding them on my function the css3 is applied to any browser. I use this only for ie6-8 browsers. My problem is how to use that function inside a modal window that is created dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i *think* what your saying is u want the styling to be on the elements you retrieved through ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.PIE) {
        go();
    }

});
function go(){
    $('.secondary, .primary, .light_gray_sub').click(function() {
            PIE.attach(this);
            alert("alert XXX");
     });
 }

$.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/test.html',
      success: function(data) {
            //append the data to the body here
            go();
      }
});
```